# Water floating on water

Tags: fluid-dynamics, surface-tension, fluid-statics

In the video made by the slo-mo guys [as shown here](http://youtube.com/watch?v=VCERs0v1OoI), at time 1:47 comes a moment when a water droplet(almost completely spherical), is seen to 'float' on the surface of the water for a while.

So why did this case arise? Is it something to do with the tuning fork, or solely a surface-tension based phenomenon? If it is the latter, why does it break back into the whole liquid,and  is there an ambient temperature and pressure for this to occur?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/256023/

Comment: Also, you can find a nice discussion here: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3208511/

Comment: Sometimes called 'antibubbles'.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can a droplet of liquid float on the surface of the same liquid?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/163013/)